# Alternatives to representation of tree data

Tags: java, android, android-listview, treeview

I have to represent tree data having number of levels in android app. As per native API, using list view we can provide only two levels. It is also reasonable because using fat fingers we can't expand or shrink tree properly.

So is there any alternative way to represent this tree like data?

Answer (score 0):

Can you not 'drill-down' by clicking on the second level.  The second level then becomes the first level (visually) and you then add in the third level as the second level (visually).  You will need a 'back' button of some sort to move back up.

Or do you need to show the whole tree at once?  What is in your tree?  Just labels/names, or multiple data values per node?

Also, a long shot - but for ideas (if you like writing your own components):

http://www.cs.umd.edu/hcil/treemap-history/

Comment: Thnx for taking interest. Actually I am interested whole data at once. Though it is not mandatory for good alternative. Also thanx for nice link.

Comment: Also for drill down, if list is long with no of levels, we might need to do no of activities making it complex. Alternative is setting in same Activity different views, then making them visible or hidden. Though it is just a thought.